# how to renders props before all other method on vue js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

> i want to load/render the props before the created method loaded. so that i can use the props on my on my created method in here in vuejs.this is the way i did it. but my created method is not receiving the data.id. how should i do it? thanks in advance.

```
 props:['data'],
    data(){
        return {
            products:{},

            abc:1,

        }
    },

    created(){
        axios.get(`/api/category/${this.data.id}`)
            .then(res => this.products = res.data.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))

        console.log(this.data.id);
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wait for data to be available before mounting your component. Let's say the component you have defined in your question is called Test. You would have to use it like this:

```
<Test :data="data" v-if="data.id"/>
```

This way you are ensuring that your data will always be available on your created() and mounted() methods.

Comment: tried it but this way it's not updating the id. on the first click it's working fine. but when i am loading the child component again it's not changing the id.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your prop `data` is empty because you can access components' props inside `created` function. You may double check [here](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/EBzoZa)

```js
const buttonCounter = {
 template:
  `<span :style="itemColor">{{newID}}</span>`,
 props: ['data', 'color'],
 created: function () {
  console.log('created ID', this.data.id)
  this.newID = `created ${this.data.id}`
 },
 data: function () {
  return {
   animal: 'horse1',
   newID: ''
  }
 },
 computed: {
  itemColor: function (){
   return {
    color: this.color,
    'margin-right': '25px'
   }
  }
 }
}

Vue.component("button-counter", buttonCounter );

new Vue({
 el: "#databinding",
 data: function() {
  return {
   colors: ["red", "yellow", "blue", "black", "grey", "green", "pink", "purple"],
   dataSrc : [{ id: 'a1'}, { id: 'a2' }, { id: 'a3'}, { id: 'a4'}, { id: 'a5'}, { id: 'a6'}, { id: 'a7'}, { id: 'a8'}]
  };
 },
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 20px;
}
.btn-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="databinding">
 <div id="counter-event-example">
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
   <button-counter v-for="(item, index) in colors" :color="item" :data="dataSrc[index]"  :key="item" ></button-counter>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am positive that my props data is not empty.